# git credential.helper does not store username password

Tags: git, bash, expect, azure-devops

I am writing a deployment script which clones a git repo and then performs other tasks such as fetch etc .I have run this

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

The username and password for cloning step are provided by an expect script.
But these details are not cached as it should be.The script again prompts for user details

I cannot use ssh as I am using Visual Studio Online

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a file `~/.netrc` like this:

```
machine github.com
login <username>
password <password>
```

and Git will use it. Another option is [git-credential-store](//git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store):

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Credentials are saved to `~/.git-credentials`.

Answer (score 13):

Very old thread, but I found it today, so...

It worked in my setup (Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS) after telling git, where to store the credentials. It seems, that there's no default for this in Ubuntu:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'
```

by combining it with:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper store
```

everything worked.

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

Comment: `git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'`

This also did the trick on the latest Manjaro image, thanks.

Comment: @NickMancuso thanks that worked for me

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on the golang:bullseye Docker image deployed on Cloud Run. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (bash):

```
$ git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'
```

after that open `.gitconfig` in your home directory and make sure there is:

```
[credential]
        helper = store --file ~/.my-credentials
```

now just simply push something, provide your credentials and they will be saved to `.my-credentials` file in home directory.

---

I'm not sure what Shoobdidoo means by:

> by combining it with:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global credential.helper store
> ```

but in my case running this after `git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'` will replace `helper = store --file ~/.my-credentials` with `helper = store` and it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The Git credential helper can only be used with git 1.7.10 or newer as stated here:

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

If you use an older version, you can still set the configuration option, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: `git version 2.1.4` and still does'nt work on Debian Stretch